# C# : Table not created in SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm a newbie in SQL Server, currently trying to create a database with tables inside. Here is the code for the database creation.

```
if not exists(select * from sys.databases where name = 'TCPDUMP') 
    CREATE DATABASE TCPDUMP 
         ON PRIMARY (NAME = TCPDUMP, 
                     FILENAME = 'P:\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Serene5\Serene5\Serene5.Web\App_Data\TCPDUMP.mdf', 
                     SIZE = 2MB, MAXSIZE = 10GB, FILEGROWTH = 10%) 
         LOG ON (NAME = TCPDUMP_Log, 
                 FILENAME = 'P:\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Serene5\Serene5\Serene5.Web\App_Data\TCPDUMP.ldf', 
                 SIZE = 1MB, MAXSIZE = 5GB, FILEGROWTH = 10%)
```

And the code of the table.

```
if not exists(select * from sys.tables where name = sample2Prot) 
    CREATE TABLE [TCPDUMP].[dbo].[sample2Prot]
    (
        [IdTransmission] INT IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL,
        [timestp]  NVARCHAR(32) NULL,
        [idq] NVARCHAR(32) NULL,
        [idz] NVARCHAR(32) NULL,
        [prot] NVARCHAR(32) NULL,
        [Lhowmany] NVARCHAR(32) NULL,
        [Rhowmany] NVARCHAR(32) NULL,

        CONSTRAINT[PK_TCPDump] 
            PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED([IdTransmission] ASC)
    )
```

However, when I do

```
SELECT * FROM [TCPDUMP].[dbo].[sample2Prot]
```

an error occurs :

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException : Invalid object name 'sample2Prot'

I suppose I made a mistake in my SQL code, but I can't figure out where and why. Has anyone an idea ?

**EDIT**: I adapted my code to your comments (inverted the `[sample2Prot].[dbo].[TCPDUMP]`, corrected the parenthesis..) but it still doesn't work

Comment: Which string actually contains string parameter `{0}`? What is the purpose of second argument `"sample2Prot"` here?

Comment: You are creating a table with the syntax CREATE TABLE[sample2Prot].[TCPDUMP] the syntax should be [Database].[schema].[tablename]. I would check your syntax directly in SQL Server first, then plug it into C#

Comment: It looks like there is a missing parentheses in your query.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto Sorry, I didn't completely adapt my code to the question.

Comment: Oh, I found that you need `[TCPDUMP].[dbo].[sample2Prot]` as your table name to use SELECT statement (TCPDUMP is your DB name, right?)

Comment: @Leonidas199x can the schema be optional ?

Comment: @DoeJowns dbo is the default schema, you can write it like [Database]..[Tablename], this will use the default schema.

Comment: If you use `USE [TCPDUMP]`, you can execute `CREATE TABLE sample2Prot` without mentioning table schema, or use `[TCPDUMP]..[sample2Prot]`.

Comment: dbo is the default schema in SQL Server, It stand for DataBase Owner

Comment: You can have multiple schema on a same database. A schema is just a set of Database Object.

Comment: Ok I did all the changes. However, it still doesn't work. I'm trying to delete previously created databases, in order to run everything from scratch, but I can't find any files in my App_Data folder. (I've enabled hidden files view). Any idea what is happening ?

Comment: @DoeJowns any errors, or the same that it did not exist when the select is run? have noticed: select * from sys.tables where name = sample2Prot should be select * from sys.tables where name = 'sample2Prot' with the table name contained in inverted commas.

Comment: Oh ok for an if/else reason the command.ExecuteNonQuery() didn't executed.. ^^ It creates the table correctly then. Thus, I get another error the 'if not exists..' part doesn't seems to function properly. The command line doesn't recognize when the database is already created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From quick view, seems that the order of database & table name is reversed there:

```
CREATE TABLE [sample2Prot].[TCPDUMP]
```

The correct naming order to create a table is *[database name].[schema name].[table name]* as shown below (`dbo` is default database object schema used by SQL Server):

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * from sys.tables where name = sample2Prot) 
    CREATE TABLE [TCPDUMP].[dbo].[sample2Prot] 
    (
        [IdTransmission] INT IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL,
        [timestp]  NVARCHAR(32) NULL,
        [idq]  NVARCHAR(32) NULL,
        [idz]  NVARCHAR(32) NULL,
        [prot]  NVARCHAR(32) NULL,
        [Lhowmany]  NVARCHAR(32) NULL,
        [Rhowmany]  NVARCHAR(32) NULL, 
        CONSTRAINT [PK_TCPDump] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([IdTransmission] ASC)
    )
```

Or using `USE [database_name]` is much simpler:

```
USE [TCPDUMP]

-- CREATE TABLE sample2Prot may used directly if dbo schema used
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[sample2Prot]
(
    -- column & constraint declarations
)
```

The SELECT statement can be configured as below:

```
USE [TCPDUMP]

SELECT * FROM sample2Prot

-- or

SELECT * FROM [TCPDUMP].[dbo].[sample2Prot]
```

Answer (score 1):

You should check your syntax in your CREATE TABLE command. It should look like this:

```
if not exists(select * from sys.tables where name = sample2Prot) 
    CREATE TABLE [TCPDUMP].[dbo].[sample2Prot]
```

Check out more syntax here if you use a database shema 
[MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql)

Then you may need to change your `SELECT` statement to:

```
SELECT * FROM [TCPDUMP].[dbo].[sample2Prot]
```

Comment: You are missing the schema, either add it or use [TCPDUMP]..[sample2Prot] to use default.

Comment: The shema is an optional value, as you can see on MSDN

Comment: Have you tried running your code? It will think TCPDUMP is the schema.

Comment: damn u are right, will change it. I thought if you dont enter a shema name, he uses the default shema (dbo)

Comment: That is true if you do not specify the database name AND the schema, it will use the default, so SELECT * FROM [Table] is the same as SELECT * FROM [DefaultSchema].[Table]